# Why can't I name this question "a tag 404 error"?

Tags: html, mysql, flask, http-status-code-404

I make flask web. If a user clicks a link of , the server has to bring data from the MySQL database and display it. but I've got '404 not found'.
It's used to work before. I don't know why this problem happened suddenly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNL0Q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nLje.png)

I made test flask app. I tried twice.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpR1S.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9MLF.png)

At first, I tried to connect the URL address with the tag, but the same problem as in main.py(original file) occurred, I thought it was a problem with the routing path, so I entered the routing path for test.py using the form tag. But I keep getting a 404 error.

Comment: If your question is about why you can't use a particular question title, you should ask in [meta].

Comment: Try using `href="/chinga"` with the leading `/` character.

Answer (score 0):

test.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
 return render_template('test.html')


'''
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
     return render_template('index.html')
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True,port=8080)
```

test.html

```
<a href="index.html">test button </a>

<!--
<form action="/index" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
-->
```

When I press the test button, I want to display index.html, but I get a 404 error.